# Odoo 10 - Javascript Query to a Model

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, point-of-sale

I'm doing:

```
var callback = new $.Deferred();
new Model('pos.order').query(['invoice_id']).filter([['id', '=', '100']])
    .first().then(function (order) {
        if (order) {
            callback.resolve(order);
        } else {
            callback.reject({code:400, message:'Missing Order', data:{}});
        }
});
```

It works fine, and returns an **Order** object. But my issue is that i want to access the relation objects (many2many, many2one), but the order object has only the ID's of his relations. For example if i want to access the `company` or `invoice` object from the **Order** that i just fetched i need to do another query and i want to get all in a single query.

Comment: i can't import query() method.
How do you do that?

With var query = require('DataModel'); i get error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below js code to call method in py to get your required data.

```
new Model("pos.order")
    .call("method_in_pos_order_model", [100])
    .then(function (result) {
          // Result is having what you want..
     });
```

**Method in Py under pos.order model**

```
@api.model
def method_in_pos_order_model(self,id):
    return self.search([('id','=',id)])
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: is not exactly what i expected but it works :D, thanks dude.

Comment: I want to achieve same thing in odoo 12. For that, I am using this._rpc but this not work. can you please help me